# Access output of terraform state file using shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, terraform, amazon-eks

I am trying capture the cluster_arn as well as cluster_name from the state fileoutput using shell script and pass them as parameters in my shell script. Can someone suggest me some approach how we can do it.

```
"aws_instance" "foo" { 
    subnet_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.subnet_id}" 
}
```

But I want to pass this subnet_id value to my shell script which is getting called in some another tf file.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information out of Terraform you can use a combination of "outputs" and the `terraform output` command.

Consider the following Terraform:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_function" {
    [...]
}

output "lambda_arn" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.my_function.arn
}
```

If you now run the following command, you would get the ARN of your Lambda function:

```sh
terraform output lambda_arn
```

The output will be a string like:

```
"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function"
```

If you want the "raw" value, you can use the `-raw` flag:

```sh
terraform output -raw lambda_arn
```

Giving you:

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function
```

In your shell script, you could now use this to store the ARN of the Lambda function in a variable:

```sh
ARN=$(terraform output lambda_arn)
echo ${ARN}
```

Comment: I am capturing the variable value in my main.tf file .                                                                                              "aws_instance" "foo" {
  # ...
  subnet_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.subnet_id}"
}.       But I want to pass this subnet_id value to my shell script which is getting called in some another tf file.
» @Jens Can you plesae help me out in this.

Comment: @knowledge20 Then please update your question and add more details. This should have been in your question from the beginning.